# Is it OK to use "if" at the end of a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, word-order, construction

Is it OK to use "if" at the end of a sentence? e.g. I saw a professor once saying:

*They can withdraw the paper you don't go to the conference **if**.*

Comment: At least in your context, "*if*" is not used properly. Your sentence will be grammatical only when used like this - *They can withdraw the paper **if** you don't go to the conference.*

Comment: You *saw* a professor once *write*, or you *heard* him or her once *say*? Big difference!

Comment: I think this question is rather iffy.

Comment: So ... what if?

Comment: As if. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hO1mSf8l6MA

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  For example, the great question:

> "What if?"

Or, as a more elaborate example:

> "I know my chances of winning the lottery are less than on in a million, but what if?"

Another example of ending a sentence with "if" would be:

> "Don't get ahead of yourself. It's not a question of when but a
>   question of if."

A third example comes from the dictionary where "[if](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/if?s=t)" is listed as a noun:

> "The future is full of ifs."

A similar take on that sentence would be:

> "My future is one giant if."

I might say that in a situation where I feel my entire situation is hanging on a single thing, like getting into medical school or getting a particular job or promotion.

But what you've written isn't grammatical.  I'm not sure if you've forgotten some words or what, but it appears to be two clauses smudged together and "if" has no obvious reference.  I have a hard time believing a professor wrote that.

Comment: These are contrived examples. The first one could never really be valid as a standalone utterance, because it's effectively a cut-down version of *What if [some contextually-relevant but unlikely thing were to be true]*. And the second one is much the same except it's specifically a cut-down version of *...but what if **I were to win the lottery**?* The third one just quirkily exploits the "use / mention" distinction. This isn't what OP is asking about.

Comment: Yes - like I said, using ***if*** as a noun (effectively, a *mention*). But I won't bandy words with you on a question that I'd probably have closed for lack of prior research even on ELL. It's got no place here.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - I was the one who gave the other two answers an upvote.

Comment: Thanks, @Justin.  I presume you're the one who gave me one, too.

Comment: Final word: [***Stop iffing and butting**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stop+iffing+and+butting%22) We can nounify or verbify just about *anything* in English, but contrived examples aren't particularly useful for someone like the OP here, who clearly needs to learn the basics before being shown how we the natives can torture our language if we feel like it.

Comment: I totally agree with what your examples.    In fact "If" can even be a standalone sentence in a dialogue.  So can it exist at the end of a sentence?  of course

Comment: Except for "What if" (which has an ellipsis), the others do not use *if* as the same POS or in the same sense. In any case, the OPs example is of a different structure.

Answer (score 2):

The professor may well have spoken correctly. It depends on the intonation and what was said before.

Student: So you’ll be there when I’m speaking?

Prof:       *If* you’re speaking, *if*.

Student: If?  What do you mean, if?

Prof:       It’s the old they-can-withdraw-your-paper-you-don’t-go-the-conference if.

Student: Yessss... that’s a definite if.

Prof:        Yep. Sometimes they just tell you to “if off” and that’s that. You’re iffed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, you can end sentences with if.

Most questions you can end with "if" without issue.  Some sentences can also end with "if".

For example:

> I'll do lunch with you if we go to an Italian restaurant, and only if.

The example you gave, however, is not correct.  The "if" at the end of the sentence has no clear reference.  Subordinate clauses always start with a subordinating conjunction.  They cannot be tacked on after the clause.

Answer (score 1):

*No natural or standard English sentence can end with **if***. That's my answer which shows a sentence ends with *if*.

Comment: Please forgive me. I was the one who downvoted your answer. +1 now that I know what you meant :)

Comment: The paradox you present is hurting my brain.  :)

Comment: Great comment. Not an answer. Flagging as "Not an answer."

Comment: Use v. reference. :)